# Maximum values of a a function using numerical methods

Tags: optimization

How can I numerically find the local maximum values of a function? $y=1000 + (100/6)xe^{\sin x}$. Interval $[0 - 100]$. I tried differentiating it but I get stuck at solving the differential being equal to zero. Is there a way to find this?

Comment: Local maximums?  Within what interval?  If you take a series $x_n=\frac{\pi}2+2\pi n$...

Comment: Sure! Local maximums. Can you please give  a longer version of the series? And any info on how to get it? Is it a taylor series?

Comment: That series is set for the maximums of $\sin x$ which will allow for starting points for the function using a numerical method.  It's just the points at which $\sin x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not bounded above. If you take $f(x) = 1000 + 100xe^{\sin(x)}$
and consider the sequence $(x_n) = 2\pi n$, you have $f(x_n) = 1000 + 100 \times 2\pi n \times e^0 = 1000 + 200\pi n$, which clearly diverges to $+\infty$.

The function is also not bounded below, using a similar reasoning with $(x_n) = -2\pi n$

For these reasons, there is no "finding maximum values" for this function.

As for local maximums, you have to study the zeroes of $f'(x)$, which are a necessary condition for extremums to be present.

Comment: I am actually looking for the local maxima.

Comment: Then you need to look for the zeroes of $f'(x)$. We have $f'(x) = 100e^{\sin(x)}(1 + x\cos(x))$, hence you need to look for the zeroes of $1 + x\cos(x)$

Comment: Which technique can I use to find the zeroes of $1 + xcos(x)$?